# Error: spawn UNKNOWN at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)

Tags: node.js, windows, ionic-framework, child-process, spawn

Recently I tried using Ionic with Angular and kept getting this error:

```
Error: spawn UNKNOWN

at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
at spawn (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
at spawn
(C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:173:12)
at Subprocess.spawn
(C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\node_modules\@ionic\utils-subprocess\dist\index.js:146:16)
at Shell.spawn (C:\Users\Colio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\shell.js:151:24)
at async AngularServeCLI.spawn (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:345:19)
at async AngularServeCLI.spawnWrapper (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:321:20)
at async AngularServeCLI.serve (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\serve.js:311:9)
at async AngularServeRunner.serveProject
(C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli\lib\project\angular\serve.js:117:9)
PS C:\Users\MyUsername\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\CurrentProject>
```

I've tried everything I can think of to solve this issue.
Apparantly I shouldn't have, because now it's spread to any NPX command using child process.
i.e. NPX create-react-app ReactTestApp or ng new

What I have tried:

- Changing versions Node
- Comparing my version of Ionic, Angular, NPM, Node to my collegues Versions who can do the same thing and it works for them,
- Reinstalling Ionic, Angular, npm, react, and even Node & NVM
- giving admin privledges to all folders and files in a prodject file and a isolated version of nvm,
- Uninstalling my virus protection software,
- Running commands from powershell as an administrator

I am on Windows 11 and I use VS Code,

Any help is **greatly** appricated and I will be watching this post like a hawk.

UPDATE: Ended up switching computers "resolving" the issue

Answer (score 4):

If you are facing a similar issue on a Mac, this command might help:

> softwareupdate --install-rosetta

It solved my problem, I tried different node versions and updated the folder permissions but nothing helped.

As I understand, the error happened because the Apple Silicon M2 Chip was not supported and rosetta translates the x64 executable to ARM which prevents the error.

I found the answer here: https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y/issues/619

Answer (score 2):

Did you install any Android emulators? I had the same issue after installing them. Try turning off Hyper-V or running this command in your Command Prompt and then restarting your PC:

```
REG add HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System /v DisableCMD /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Also, these two links might help you:

[Error message: spawn UNKNOWN](https://hackolade.com/help/ErrormessagespawnUNKNOWN.html#:%7E:text=The%20message%20%22errorMsg%22%3A%20%22,or%20running%20Git%20binary%20commands.) 
[Enable Command Prompt](https://www.tweakandtrick.com/2013/08/enable-command-prompt.html)

Comment: Yes, I did install an emulator! I'll check that out!

Comment: I already tried going to the registry editor and running that command, I tried doing the whole process over again, uninstalling android studio, and restarting my computer, and It's still not working, :'(

Comment: Maybe try turning off the VM-Plattform in Windows-Features, restarting your computer, and then turning the VM-Plattform back on and restarting your PC again.

Comment: Still nothing, I wonder if my version of node is corrupted, which wouldn't make any sense to me since I reinstalled node and NVM

Comment: Maybe you can try the same with the Windows Feature Windows-Subsytem for Linux.
Sadly after i tried everything several times it just started working again so i cant determine what really fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error solved it by unninstalling my antivirus.

Comment: I already tried uninstalling McAfee didn't work

Comment: try to disable windows antivirus too

Comment: Iooks like I've already it had it off